An error during process termination with exit code -1
when i run the following code, i have to stop the execution two times and i always get: Process finished with exit code -1. Can you let me know what are the possible solutions?
The error
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import joblib
import time
import ipaddress
import os
import subprocess
import threading
from pandas.errors import EmptyDataError
global counter
global ArrayIndexes

counter = 0
ArrayIndexes = []


def sniffer():
    command = 'C:/Users/ccsit/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python311/Scripts/cicflowmeter.exe -i Wi-Fi -c output.csv'
    subprocess.run(command, check=True, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                   stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)


def Predict(df1):
    global counter
    # returns Series
    df1 = df1.replace(np.nan, 0)
    # returns DF
    df = pd.DataFrame([df1.rename(None)])
    # convert
    df['int_src_ip'] = df['src_ip'].apply(lambda x: int(ipaddress.IPv4Address(x)))
    df['int_dst_ip'] = df['dst_ip'].apply(lambda x: int(ipaddress.IPv4Address(x)))

    df['src_ip'] = df['src_ip'].astype('str').str.replace(r".", r"", regex=False)
    df["src_ip"] = df["src_ip"].apply(lambda x: int(x))
    df['dst_ip'] = df['dst_ip'].astype('str').str.replace(r".", r"", regex=False)
    df["dst_ip"] = df["dst_ip"].apply(lambda x: int(x))

    df["src_ip"] = df['int_src_ip']
    df["dst_ip"] = df['int_dst_ip']

    counter += 1

    x1 = df[['src_ip', 'dst_ip', 'src_port', 'dst_port', 'flow_duration', 'tot_bwd_pkts', 'fwd_pkt_len_min',
             'bwd_pkt_len_max',
             'bwd_pkt_len_min', 'psh_flag_cnt', 'ack_flag_cnt', 'pkt_size_avg']]
    print("*", DT_from_joblib.predict(x1))


DT_from_joblib = joblib.load('C:/Users/ccsit/Desktop/Gib/my_model_DT.pkl')


def check_file_modification(filename):
    while True:
        if os.path.exists(filename):
            try:

                try:
                    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
                except EmptyDataError as m:
                    continue

                # Process each row of the DataFrame
                for index, row in df.iterrows():
                    if index in ArrayIndexes:
                        continue
                    else:
                        Predict(row)
                        ArrayIndexes.append(index)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error occurred while predicting: {e}")
        time.sleep(0.1)  # Adjust the sleep duration as needed


def s():
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=sniffer)
    t1.start()

    # Specify your CSV file path
    csv_file_path = r'C:\Users\ccsit\Desktop\Gib\output.csv'

    check_file_modification(csv_file_path)

    try:
        # Keep the script running indefinitely
        while True:
            time.sleep(10)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit(0)
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        s()
        while threading.active_count() > 0:
            time.sleep(0.1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit(0)

i tried to use try and except, and i also tried to search for a solution but it seems that this exit code might mean different things.
